# Numpy is not working in Spyder 3.8 (Python 3)

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

With the help from [python Spyder not importing numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490113/python-spyder-not-importing-numpy?newreg=552a472a3ca34013ae33c242cb5d4afd)
I am trying to run this code from Spyder but it is not working though I  have installed Numpy via the command "conda install numpy"

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[1,0,0],
          [0,1,0],
          [0,0,1]])
print(a)
```

The output in the console in "No module named numpy"
Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try "pip install numpy"

Comment: The problem is that whatever interpreter your Spyder IDE is using is not the one where you installed numpy (you have multiple installations)

Comment: IIRC somewhere in Spyder's settings there's an option to change/view the currently used python interpreter. Try to set it to a python executable for which you did install numpy, or copy the path that is currently there and run `/path/to/python/executable/python -m pip install numpy`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes you are correct. When I am entering Syper via terminal then this "numpy" is working properly. But when I am entering Spyder via my installed application there "numphy" is not working. Could you please advice me that how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't use Spyder, but IDEs will generally allow you to set the interpreter, you're going to have to look that up or figure it out

Comment: which is IDE is better to use?

Comment: Just in case, to change the interpreter or use packages with the installer version of Spyder maybe this video could be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7Njb3xO4Fw